# Regular expression for allow multiple email ids sepearted by comma,should not allow multiple commas at the end and in between two email ids

Tags: .net, regex

Regular expression for allow multiple email ids separated by comma,should not allow multiple commas at the end and in between two email ids.

My regular expression for allow multiple email id's  is `((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*)*`

But it is allowing multiple commas at the end of the email id and inbetween two email ids
For ex:

```
 **test@abc.com,,test2@abc.com,,**
```

this should not be allowed

Comment: `fnord+@example.com` and `*@dk` are also syntactically valid email addresses. Please don't create yet another ad-hoc address filter which rejects valid addresses and permits invalid ones.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `([,])*` part to `([,])?` to allow 0 or 1 commas there instead of any number of commas.

Comment: How can we specify the no's commas neede?

Comment: Both * and ? will allow 0 matches, i.e., no commas. If you instead want exactly one comma between addresses and after the last one you just type (,)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the character limit `{1}` after `[,]` comma case as I have put in below..

```
((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,]{1})*)*
```

### Update 1

I have not much expertise in regex but this will work,

```
^(.+@[^\.].*\.[a-z]{2,})(;.+@[^\.].*\.[a-z]{2,})*$
```

### Update 2

```
^(\s*,?\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})+\s*$
```

Passes for

- test@abc.com,test2@abc.com
- test@abc.com test2@abc.com
- test@abc.com
- test@abc.com, test@abc.com

**Reference:**

- [Regex only numbers and dot or comma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5457460/468718)
- [Regular Expression for multiple email address](http://forums.devshed.com/html-programming-1/regular-expression-for-multiple-email-address-116776.html)

Comment: NO hari it is not wroking as expected

Comment: No Hari,in the middle of 2 mails it si accepting doubble commas Like test@abc.com,,test2@abc.com..It should accept only one comma...

Comment: Try the new regex. I had have added the test cases also this time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this :

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}){1}($|\;([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}))+)$
```

For better explanations *(I concatenated so many suggested solutions across the web)* I invite you to use this awesome tools which explains really well RegExp parts:

https://regex101.com/r/e09X7F/1

**In short :**

- My value starts and ends by a mail address

OR

- My value starts by a mail address and is followed by a mail address preceded by a ";" and ends by this couple "*;mail_address*".