# Mobile Safari - Invoke Secondary Keyboard on input type="text"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

`<input type="text">` brings up this keyboard:

[image: text keyboard]

while `<input type="number">` brings up this one:

[image: numerical/secondary keyboard]

Is there a way to keep the input type text and invoke the second keyboard? perhaps with a pattern attribute?

My issue with input type="number" is that the user is expected to input fractions and `$("#input_id").val();` is having trouble with space and forward slash, e.g `3 5/6` returns `3` and `7/13` returns `7`.

if this can be bypassed i can also work with that.

Answer (score -1):

`<input type="text">` will always invoke primary keyboard.

What you can do is:

- Prevent user from typing any character other than 0-9 and .(dot) by
  [checking keycode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764821/best-way-to-restrict-a-text-field-to-numbers-only) or by [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457416/regex-only-numbers-and-dot-or-comma)
  eg: `[0-9][.][0-9]{1-2}` returns true for one or two decimal places.
- Add some validation rule to the input field and show error when user submits the form

Comment: I am not worried about input validation but ease of use. I don't want the user to have to switch keyboards even once, let alone every character.

Comment: Why don't you use `<input type="number">` to invoke secondary keyboard directly and then prevent input of those special characters.

Comment: My issue with input type="number" is that the user is expected to input fractions and $("#input_id").val(); is having trouble with space and forward slash, e.g 3 5/6 returns 3 and 7/13 returns 7